# Grep spotify songname into text file from html doc

Tags: bash, http, shell, curl, spotify

I am building a script to grep the song name (and maybe the artist) and output it to a text file.

Let's say that we are using the http url "http://open.spotify.com/track/2TPEDo3bJrmhmDxB2Wi3Kw" and we want to output the song name into a text file.

I've come this far:

```
machine@user:/i/am/a/patch$ curl http://open.spotify.com/track/2TPEDo3bJrmhmDxB2Wi3Kw | grep h1 >> test.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10291    0 10291    0     0  55260      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 77962
machine@user:/i/am/a/patch$ cat test.txt

          <h1 itemprop="name">Gold Dust (Flux Pavilion Remix)</h1>
machine@user:/i/am/a/patch$
```

The problem here is that I have some useless data here ".."
And I only want the song name.

Also, the artist would be nice too.

It is going to be different spotify url's every time, so I can't grep the song name.

I am stuck here so hope someone can help me, thanks!

/Phew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\"name\">)[^<]+(?=</h1>)' test.txt
```

Comment: Great, thanks. 
That got it to work.

Just need the artist now, but thanks! :)